# How to set maximum size of file from File Picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, filepicker

this is my code

```
Uint8List? filePath1;
  File? file1;


  Future transferCertificatePick() async {

    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result == null) return;
    Uint8List? fileBytes1 = result.files.first.bytes;
    final path = result.files.first.name;
    setState(() {
      file1 = File(path);
      filePath1 = fileBytes1;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deprecated Answer:**

To set a maximum file size for the selected file, you can use the maxFileSize parameter when calling the FilePicker method.

```dart
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  maxFileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // 5MB in bytes
);
```

**Updated Answer:**

You can get the size of the picked file with `result.files.first.size` and check if it's less than the max size or not. Here is an example.

```
double _sizeKbs = 0;
final int maxSizeKbs = 1024;

void onFilePicked() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if(result != null) {
      final size = result.files.first.size;
      _sizeKbs = size/1024;
      if(_sizeKbs > maxSizeKbs) {
        print('size should be less than $maxSizeKbs Kb');
      } else {
        print('file size accepted');
        //Upload your file
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no maxFileSize parameter in filepicker.its not working

Comment: You are welcome Naveen